# Selenium with APEX applications : How to look for a Web Element?

Tags: java, oracle, css, selenium

We are a french firm that develops around ten APEX applications in production (Apex 5, Oracle 11g and 12c). In this context, we need to automate UI tests apex applications. We have chosen Selenium, with Java programming  (version 2.53.1).

To search for an element in the page DOM, we use "findElement(By.id())". For this, we have added static IDs on Apex components (i.e. Region, ...) because we have a multi-tenant approach: *an apex application can be deployed in several workspace of the same Oracle instance (Apex application ID and offset are declared during installation process)*.

It is also possible to search for an element based on its CSS class, with CSS3 approach implemented in Apex5.

We have the following questions :

- Would you recommend to search for an element with the DOM or with CSS3 ?
- Will CSS selector be maintained for future apex release ?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because half the question calls for an opinion, the other half requires predicting the future.

Comment: what is the problem that you are trying to address?